# Vagrant vagrantfile version mismatch

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

my versions:

```
VBoxManage --version
5.1.28r117968

vagrant -v
Vagrant 2.0.0
```

when i run vagrant up i get an output like
when i run vagrant up i get an output like

```
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The plugins failed to load properly. The error message given is
shown below.

This Vagrant environment has specified that it requires the Vagrant
version to satisfy the following version requirements:

~> 1.5

You are running Vagrant 2.0.0, which does not satisfy
these requirements. Please change your Vagrant version or update
the Vagrantfile to allow this Vagrant version. However, be warned
that if the Vagrantfile has specified another version, it probably has
good reason to do so, and changing that may cause the environment to
not function properly.
```

what am i need?

Comment: can you run `vagrant plugin list`

Comment: `vagrant-berkshelf (5.1.1)
  - Version Constraint: >=2.0.1  |
vagrant-share (1.1.9, system)
  - Version Constraint: > 0  |
vagrant-vbguest (0.14.2)
  - Version Constraint: > 0  |
vagrant-vmware-workstation (4.0.24)
  - Version Constraint: > 0`

Answer (score 0):

And the guilty is **Vagrant-bershelf** has a strong dependency on 1.x branch of vagrant as you can check from this [line of code](https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/blob/master/lib/vagrant-berkshelf/plugin.rb#L16)

```
module Berkshelf
  class Plugin < Vagrant.plugin("2")
    # Require a particular version of Vagrant
    Vagrant.require_version("~> 1.5")

    name "berkshelf"
```

You have the following possible solution:

- If you dont need the plugin, just uninstall it
- You would need to ask the owner of the plugin to upgrade to 2.x now (or provide a pull request to the project with the upgrade)
- revert to 1.9x vagrant version